# How to comment Jenkins scheduled build scripts

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-scriptler

I have Jenkins schedule scripts to trigger commands on certain days of the week.

```
H 6 * * 1 MY_CMD1
H 6 * * 2 MY_CMD2
H 6 * * 3 MY_CMD3
H 6 * * 4 MY_CMD4
```

this will trigger the respective command on a respective day at 6 AM.

I want to skip `H 6 * * 3 MY_CMD3` for a few coming weeks. How can I comment this?

Comment: @IanW Please provide that in answer section and A.Shenoy mark it as answer if it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefix the line with "#".

As can be gleaned from the "Build periodically | Schedule" help (?) example:

> ```
> Examples: 
> # every fifteen minutes (perhaps at :07, :22, :37, :52)
> H/15 * * * *
> # every ten minutes in the first half of every hour (three times, perhaps at :04, :14, :24)
> H(0-29)/10 * * * *
> ```

The scheduler inherits the same comment syntax as [crontab](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab)